# show drop down list if condition is met

Tags: excel, vba

I've seen few threads about dependable drop down lists, but none of them quite gives me the idea, how to accomplish this. I have "C" column where info is filled by VLOOKUP function from another sheets table and I need an option which would check If in Column A cell typed value is equal to = 001377, then it should give me drop down list with two values, if not then continue to use VLOOKUP function further without any lists. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

    'Change sheet name if needed
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To LastRow

            If .Range("A" & i).Value = "001377" Then
                'Replace Formula1:="1,2" with the two values that you want to appear in the drop down
                With .Range("C" & i).Validation
                    .Delete
                    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
                    xlBetween, Formula1:="1,2"
                    .IgnoreBlank = True
                    .InCellDropdown = True
                    .InputTitle = ""
                    .ErrorTitle = ""
                    .InputMessage = ""
                    .ErrorMessage = ""
                    .ShowInput = True
                    .ShowError = True
                End With

            Else
                'Code for VLOOKUP
            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```